# how to update the value inside object with increment process mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document

```
    "watched": {
        "1": true,
       "2": true, //should add 3 with true value
    },
   "fans": 4 //should increment by 5 it should be 9
```

when ever I do update it should increase the key and value and update the fans increment by 5

```
db.getCollection('movies').updateOne({
    _id: Object_id("60e80c96b9c55e7a01898f5c")
},  { $set: { "watched.3": true} }  },
    { $inc: { fans: 5 } } 
)
```

EITHER it does update or increment how to manage both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: ObjectId("60e80c96b9c55e7a01898f5c"),
  "watched.3": {
    $exists: false
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "watched.3": true
  },
  $inc: {
    fans: 5
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y-fWh6ib80K)

Comment: if key is already exists "watched.3": true it should not increment the value

Comment: @simon I update my answer

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/UkmLdKm-Et3
can you please check 
if watched.3 exists then remover 3 and fans = -2 else add watched.3 and fans +1 – 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70965650/how-to-pull-and-add-base-on-condition-mongodb/70965825#70965825

Comment: @simon [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4udt311wt_8)

Comment: Sir thank you very much really it turning to be big help thank you